# App.config settings for EF5 codefirst and SQL CE

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, sql-server-ce

I'm having trouble building a small console app with just a couple of classes using EF5 and code first with a SQL Compact database.  Apparently there have been some changes with the latest version of EF that may be getting in my way.  Could you point me to a resource that would properly cover the changes needed to the app.config and if needed machine.config in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact NuGet package, it will add all the required config setting for you.

Comment: I was able to use the NuGet package, but not for EF5 as the NuGet package was configured for EF6 only and there was no EF5 version that I could find.  I upgraded my solution to use EF6 instead.  Thanks